# Back to Collaborate from Plastic SCM

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control, collaboration, plasticscm

I want to turn off the Plastic SCM and start using Collaborate as it was before. We are get used to it and we don't need Plastic SCM. I turned off Plactic SCM in its preferences, turned on Collaborate and I get this error

```
[Collab] ReposController::CreateRepoError: Organization has been migrated to Plastic SCM, refusing to create new project in Collab. Please see: https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/PlasticSCMPlugin.html
```

And Collaborate window says: Cannot get revision from server.

I have Unity Collaborate Package version of 1.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collaborate is going to be deprecated very soon and I'm afraid once an organization is migrated to Plastic SCM, you cannot go back.